# DnD 4th edition, teleport and charging

Tags: dnd-4e, charge

Can the movement from a teleport power be used as the movement in a charge if you teleport two or more squares?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**

From the RC, p240:

> **Charge**
>
> *Action:* Standard action. When a creature takes this action, it chooses a target. Figure out how far away the creature is from the target--even counting through squares of blocking terrain--and then follow these steps:
>
> *1. Move:* The creature moves up to its speed toward the target. Each square of movement must bring the creature closer to the target, and the creature must end the move at least 2 squares away from its starting position.

Charging is already an action. You can't use another power to replace the movement in a charge because the movement is *part* of an action.

An argument could be made that you could teleport as part of a charge if you have teleportation as an actual movement mode (at least one epic destiny offers this), but teleport powers definitely won't work.

There is, however, *one* exception to this rule, the Fey Charge feat from Martial Power:

> **Fey Charge**
>
> *Prerequisites:* eladrin, 11th level, fighter
>
> *Benefit:* When you charge, you can expend your fey step racial power as a free action to replace up to 5 squares of your charge movement with teleportation. If the charge attack hits, you do not expend fey step.